# count the total number of residues in a text file

Tags: awk

I have some text files as shown below. I need to count the total number of residues in each file. The 6th column represents the residue numbers.

file1.txt

```
ATOM     19  CA  LYS C 323       2.648  17.703  45.442  1.00 17.46           C 
ATOM     20  C   LYS C 323       1.884  18.118  46.688  1.00 17.13           C 
ATOM     21  O   LYS C 323       0.822  17.576  46.996  1.00 17.54           O 
ATOM     28  CA  ARG C 324       1.835  19.574  48.632  1.00 16.33           C  
ATOM     29  C   ARG C 324       1.990  21.084  48.733  1.00 16.43           C      
ATOM     45  N   LYS C 326       2.321  24.344  50.724  1.00 16.55           N  
ATOM     46  CA  LYS C 326       2.843  24.570  52.063  1.00 15.26           C
ATOM     62  N   ASP C 328       1.791  25.643  56.502  1.00 22.19           N
ATOM     63  CA  ASP C 328       2.336  25.657  57.860  1.00 23.53           C
```

file2.txt

```
ATOM     12  CG  GLN B 670      52.075  84.009  47.855  1.00 97.39           C  
ATOM     13  CD  GLN B 670      51.068  83.904  46.726  1.00 98.36           C  
ATOM     14  OE1 GLN B 670      51.239  84.504  45.665  1.00100.00           O
ATOM     16  N   SER B 671      49.664  86.399  49.090  1.00 88.49           N  
ATOM     17  CA  SER B 671      48.384  87.100  49.166  1.00 79.72           C
```

Desired Output

```
Total no:of residues in file1.txt : 4   
Total no:of residues in file2.txt : 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this awk one-liner:

```
awk '{a[$6]} END{print "Total no:of residues in", FILENAME, ":", length(a)}' file
```

**Alternate non-gnu awk solution:**

```
awk '{a[$6]} END{for (i in a) s++;print "Total no:of residues in", FILENAME, ":",s}' file
```

Comment: A nice way to get the numbers of element in an array, I would how used `split` and not thought `length` work this way.  You can save one character by using `{a[$6]++}` instead of `!a[$6]++{}`

Comment: @Jotne: You can save two more, because the OP doesn't seem to care about the counts. You can just use: `{ a[$6] }`.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks! Good point, edited further to save another 2 characters.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your answer. Your code doesn't work. I get the error like this awk: line 1: illegal reference to array a

Comment: Try this and see if it works. `awk '{a[$6]} END{for (i in a) s++;print "Total no:of residues in", FILENAME, ":",s}' file`

Comment: The issue is that using length() to find the number of elements in an array is gawk-specific.

Comment: I have added alternate solution also, see if that helps OP.

Comment: I suppose other awks may have implemented that too, but it's not common.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, untested:

```
awk '
!seen[FILENAME,$6]++ { numRes[FILENAME]++ }
END {
    for (fileName in numRes) {
        printf "Total no:of residues in %s : %d\n", fileName, numRes[fileName]
    }
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```